# Custom font not applying React Native Elements Button component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Not able to set custom font for Button in react native element.

I am using "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1" version and trying to set custom font for the button. Already the font is working in the page for Text component.

```
<Button
        rightIcon={{ name: 'history', type: 'font-awesome'}}
        transparent={true}
        title='History'
        fontSize={18}
        fontWeight='bold'
        fontFamily='montserrat'
      />
```

But the font is not changing or not throwing any error. I tried to give fontFamily "textStyle", "titleStyle" prop also. No luck.

Font inclusion snippet,

```
async componentWillMount() {
try{
  await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
    montserrat: require("./assets/fonts/Montserrat.ttf"),
    montserrat_light: require("./assets/fonts/Montserrat_light.ttf")
  });
  this.setState({ loading: false });
}catch(error){
  console.warn('Error loading fonts', error);
}
```

}

Note : Custom fonts are loaded using componentWillMount method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the code where you're adding the font, does `rnpm` not work

Comment: Updated, pls check

Comment: Can you try adding it as`textStyle={{fontFamily: 'montserrat'}}`

Comment: have you tried loading the font in a normal `<Text>` component using the style prop?

Comment: can you try using titleStyle={{ fontSize: 18 }} in the button props?

Comment: @Chandini font size is working fine. I am facing issue in fontFamily only.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak: yes, working fine with <Text> component.

Comment: @Akilan then can you try giving fontFamily props inside titleStyle like this.  titleStyle={{ fontFamily: 'montserrat' }} in the button props

Comment: @Chandini I tried that too. Not working.

Comment: Could it be `'montserrat'` should be title case: `'Montserrat'`? great font btw

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak No, we have to use the same case that we given in Async.

Comment: maybe your `Button` component isn't rerendering? try passing it `this.state.loading` as a prop so it updates when you set state

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I am using button component inside the this.state.loading only. I have no clue why it not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. The problem is `fontWeight` given for the button. We have to define the Bold font in the Async font loading and call the name in fontFamily.

The following script will resolve my issue,

```
<Button
        rightIcon={{ name: 'history', type: 'font-awesome'}}
        transparent={true}
        title='History'
        fontSize={18}
        fontFamily='montserrat_bold'
      />
```

And we need to define the font path in Async like below,

```
async componentWillMount() {
try{
  await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
    montserrat: require("./assets/fonts/Montserrat.ttf"),
    montserrat_light: require("./assets/fonts/Montserrat_light.ttf"),
    montserrat_bold: require("./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf")
  });
  this.setState({ loading: false });
}catch(error){
  console.warn('Error loading fints', error);
}
```

}

Comment: I did the same but still not solved, even though the fontSize won't work